# Rails use an instance variable in controller or generate within a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to build out on an Invoice page the past_due_amount where I'm trying to find only the invoices for the current account, that are not paid off, and should be in the past.

So roughly I have:

```
past_due_amount = Invoice.where(account: invoice.account, status: :unpaid).where('date < ? ', invoice.date).map(&:due).sum
```

For additional context here are the models involved:

Invoice:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :account

 has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :payment_destinations, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :prorated_fees, dependent: :nullify

 enum status: [:unpaid, :paid]

 validates :date, presence: true
 validates :period_start, :period_end,
   uniqueness: { scope: :account, allow_blank: true }, on: :create
 validate :start_is_before_end

 DAYS_DUE_AFTER_DATE = 14.days

 scope :descending, -> { order(date: :desc) }
 scope :ascending, -> { order(date: :asc) }
 scope :due, -> { unpaid.where(arel_table[:date].lteq(Time.zone.today - DAYS_DUE_AFTER_DATE)) }

 def total
  if persisted?
    line_items.sum(:amount)
  else
    line_items.map(&:amount).sum
  end
```

end
    end

Account:

```
 class Account < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :customer
 belongs_to :property_address,
   class_name: Address.to_s,
   dependent: :destroy,
   required: false

 [:products, :account_changes, :equipments,
  :payments, :invoices].each do |assoc|
   has_many assoc, dependent: :destroy
 end

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_address
 delegate :street, :city, :state, :zip,
   to: :property_address, allow_nil: true
 delegate :email, :full_name, to: :customer

 enum status: [:staged, :active, :inactive]

 scope :active_or_staged, -> { where(status: [:staged, :active]) }
 scope :past_due, lambda {
   joins(:invoices)
     .where(
       Invoice.arel_table[:status].eq(:unpaid)
       .and(Invoice.arel_table[:date].lt(Time.zone.today - 14.days))
     ).distinct
 }

 scope :search, lambda { |term|
   joins(:customer)
     .where(
       arel_table[:account_num].matches("%#{term}%")
       .or(Customer.arel_search(term))
     )
 }
end
```

With the rough code in place I decided to build out a instance variable on the InvoicesController within the show method as below:

```
 def show
  @invoice = Invoice.find_by!(id: params[:id], account: current_customer.account_ids)
  @account = @invoice.account
  @past_due_amount = Invoice.where(account: @account, status: :unpaid).where('date < ?', @invoice.date).map(&:due).sum
 end
```

No errors appear but that's not saying much since the examples I have are poor, at best. But my question is...should I actually be putting this in a helper instead of the show method on an InvoicesController or even in the model?

EDIT:

I've also tried putting in my Invoice model:

```
def self.past_due_amount
 Invoice.where(account: @account, status: :unpaid).where('date < ?', @invoice.date).map(&:due).sum
end
```

Then in my InvoicesController:

```
def show
 @invoice = Invoice.find_by!(id: params[:id], account: current_customer.account_ids)
 @account = @invoice.account
 @past_due_amount = Invoice.past_due_amount
end
```

End up getting undefined method `date' for @invoice.date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a method `past_due_amount` in the `InvoicesHelper`

```
module InvoicesHelper

  def past_due_amount
    Invoice.where(account: @account, status: :unpaid).where('date  <?', @invoice.date).map(&:due).sum
   end
end
```

In you controller just initialize all the instance variables

```
def show
 @invoice = Invoice.find_by!(id: params[:id], account: current_customer.account_ids)
 @account = @invoice.account
end
```

In the view you should use: `<%= past_due_amount >` to show your data

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance method in `Account` model

```
def past_due_amount
  invoices.map(&:due).sum
end
```

and then from view you can all it `@account.past_due_amount`. no need to create extra instance variable in controller action

Answer (score 0):

So I sort of used Patrick's answer but it was actually failing so I switched to passing invoice as params.

Helper

```
module InvoicesHelper
 def past_due_amount(invoice)
  Invoice.where(account: invoice.account, status: :unpaid).where('date < ?', invoice.date).map(&:due).sum
 end
end
```

Then in my view:

```
<% if past_due_amount(invoice).positive? %>
 <p><%= number_to_currency past_due_amount(invoice) %></p>
<% end %>
```